# С# как сложить время, если строковые значения?

Tags: c#

Как сложить время, если строковые значения ?

Допустим имею 2 переменные `string time1 = "1:23"` и `string time2 = "0:54"`

Как их сложить ?

Comment: Преобразовать оба значения в DateTime и сложить.

Comment: Здорово ! Спасибо ! DateTime ещё не проходил.

Comment: @АртемНиколаевич, скорее в TimeSpan

Comment: @Grundy Верно, спасибо.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
TimeSpan s1 = TimeSpan.Parse("1:23");
TimeSpan s2 = TimeSpan.Parse("0:54");
TimeSpan s3 = s1 + s2;
```

[Ссылка](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

Как уже было сказано нужно преобразовать оба значения в DateTime и сложить.

```
string time1 = "1:23";
string time2 = "0:54";

DateTime t1 = DateTime.Parse(time1);
DateTime t2 = DateTime.Parse(time2);

Console.WriteLine(t1.TimeOfDay + t2.TimeOfDay);
```