# С# как преобразовать "2 ч 46 мин" в TimeSpan?

Tags: c#

С# как преобразовывать подобные строковые значения `string time1 = "2 ч 46 мин"` и `string time2 = "54 мин"` в TimeSpan ?

Только недавно задавал вопрос, но не верно указал строковые значения, поэтому не выходит.

[С# как сложить время, если строковые значения ?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/735211/)

Comment: Преобразуйте строку "2 ч 46 мин" в "2:46". Можно просто через time1.Replace(" ч ", ":") и т.п.

Comment: @АртемНиколаевич как это делается ? С помощью форматирования ? string.format или как ? Что мне нужно сделать или почитать ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
String[] formats = { @"h\ \ч\ mm\ \м\и\н", @"mm\ \м\и\н" };
String[] values = { "2 ч 46 мин", "54 мин" };

foreach (string value in values)
{
     var parsed = TimeSpan.ParseExact(value, formats, System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
     Console.WriteLine(parsed);
}
```

02:46:00

00:54:00

Comment: а что так можно было?!(c) красивое решение, возьму на заметку

Comment: Да, синтаксис строки формата TimeSpan в .NET оставляет желать лучшего. Необходимость экранировать каждый символ добавляет веселья. :)

Comment: @LunarWhisper а как подобное провернуть в обратную сторону из 12:30:00 -> в 12 ч 30 мин ?

Comment: @Vipz точно так-же: `ts.ToString(@"hh\ \ч\ mm\ \м\и\н")`
Символом \ ты экранируешь любой символ не являющийся часть формата, включая пробел.